# declaration of global in tkinter with import of module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import calculation_feet_metres
from calculation_feet_metres import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Feet to Metres")

'''
def calculate(*args):
    try:

        value = float(feet.get())
        metres.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass
'''

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
feet =StringVar()
metres = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W,E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = metres).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command = calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='feet').grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='is equivalent to').grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text ='metres').grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
   child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

The above returns

```
    value = float(feet.get())
NameError: global name 'feet' is not defined.
```

If I 'activate' the function `def calculate(*arg)` and comment out the `import calculation_feet_metres`, the converter works (copied from Modern Tkinter).

I am trying to understand how to import a module (in this case I also have a module containing the same `def calculate(*arg)` script called `calculation_feet_metres`) and call a function from the module. I don't understand where to define, nor how to define in this context, the global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions imported from a different module cannot see globals in the module they were imported *to*.

Globals are 'local' to the module a function is defined in only.

You could wrap your function in a lambda:

```
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command = lambda: calculate(feet)).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
```

and alter your `calculate` function to accept `feet` as an explicit argument:

```
def calculate(feet):
```

Comment: with this I get an error that I am presenting 0 arguments to lambda. I afraid that I am very new to this so I don't really understand am simply reproducing what you have written, so perhaps you have assumed something that I ought to know??? to make this work

Comment: @user1478335: sorry, my mistake, the button `command` parameter does not take any arguments. I removed the `a` argument.